# Delete Cascade property is not getting registered in the database

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I'm creating a hotel booking api having the following entities.

Hotel.java

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Hotel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long id;

    // other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Room.java

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long id;

    // other fields
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id")
    Hotel hotel;
}
```

HotelRepository.java

```java
import com.hotel.api.booking.model.Hotel;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<Hotel, Long> {
}
```

And inside a controller I’m trying to delete the hotel entity using the code below

```java
    @Transactional
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public EntityCreatedDTO deleteHotel(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Hotel targetHotel = hotelRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        hotelRepo.delete(targetHotel);
        return new EntityCreatedDTO(targetHotel.getId(), "Hotel deleted successfully");
    }
```

When i send a delete request to the end point above, I get a 403 Forbidden with following exception.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "hotel" violates foreign key constraint "fkdosq3ww4h9m2osim6o0lugng8" on table "room"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "room".
```

I set show-sql property to true. This is the DDL query hibernate issues to create the relation.

```sql
alter table if exists room 
       add constraint FKdosq3ww4h9m2osim6o0lugng8 
       foreign key (hotel_id) 
       references hotel
```

No sign of cascade property ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

I already have a work around I just want to know why?

Thanks :)

Comment: can you share us your workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

`Cascade` of JPA/Hibernate is completely unrelated to the `cascade` option of foreign key constraints in database. It means that definitions are not translated into DDL, they tell Hibernate how to behave when an operation is performed.

My opinion is to create first database with models with all the staff(PK, FK, Constraints, `cascade`…) and after it translate it to Entities(JPA/Hibernate)

It is the best approach for production project.